# Minecraft Command Issues

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I’m building a small village on a huge flat top hill. I can’t be bothered to mine out all the grass. I can’t use commands to build the actual road because you can only use commands for white concrete. My problem is the command block says *cannot execute command because the location is out of the world*. I’M STANDING THERE ON GROUND I’M IN THE WORLD. The command I’m trying to do is this: 
**/fill 799 79 -30 331 79 -34 air**
I have checked that air is a valid block to place. I also used a command block 20 blocks away from where I want the road to be so I am extremely confused.

Comment: What are your current coordinates?

Comment: Does the command work with smaller coordinates? Fill has a limit, so you might be surpassing it. Try splitting the command in two. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel definitely not the limit; the block volume i'm getting (if i did the math right) doesn't even hit the 2000 mark.

Comment: This is late, but you have always been able to fill with colored concrete since it came out. Just use data values